# Why use a token/OIDC server for two types of client apps?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor, openid-connect

I'm building a system like this:

- a single API server (ASP.NET Core 5)
- a SPA client (Blazor)
- a mobile client (Xamarin)
- the API is only used by my users, via my client apps; I'd like to add social logins too

For auth, I have prior experience with Identity and JWTs (access/refresh tokens, etc.).

But, in this case of two clients, I've read it's better to use a token server (OAuth/OIDC e.g. IdentityServer4). It feels like overkill, but all the docs I've read are pushing me to implement a token server - in fact the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0) say:

> To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the following: Azure Active Directory, Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C), IdentityServer4

I understand what such a server does, I just don't see how it helps me unless I'm building a major enterprise app.

*Please help me understand how that would simplify my work? Why is it better than Identity+JWTs for both clients?*

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. In you other projects, where you gain experience with JWTs, what service generated the token? AzureAd or another service?

Is your API used by users or by other applications?  Do you have local users, or do you have external (social) logins, or both? How many services (API) should need authentication?

Comment: @Justthebenno In my previous experience with JWTs I generated the tokens myself. Both in aspnet core and in node - was much easier than it's made out to be. As far as your other points, sorry for not mentioning it... I've updated the post.

Comment: My first reaction is to use IdentityServer4, but maybe I don't see the whole picture. How would you handle the redirect from a social login provider with the Xamarin app? A user clicks the "login via Google" button. You generate the needed request URL and open WebView with it. The user logins and is finally redirected back to your application. What URL would you use?  Of course, you could use localhost and listening for the URI changes and as soon as it starts with localhost. You extract the token, closes the WebView, and save the token. Using localhost, however, has "visual" drawbacks.

Comment: Next point, how would you handle multiple social login providers? Per the authentication schema, you could only have on authority. Your client app needs to use a different authentication header based on the used social login provider.  So if the first social login provider is used, a header like ```Authorization BearerGoogle <TokenValue>``` should be added to the request, and if the second is used, your clients would add  ``` ```Authorization BearerTwitter <TokenValue>```

Comment: The configuration in the API is something like ```services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("BearerGoogle ", (options) => { options.Authority = <GoogleEndpoint>; }).AddJwtBearer("BearerTwitter ", (options) => { options.Authority = <TwitterEndpoint>; });``` So, IdentityServer4 would simplify it by acting as a gateway. I'm used to using IdentityServer4. But maybe you are right, and it's a lot of effort, and I'm in "If all you got is a hammer, everything is looking like a nail" thinking trap

Comment: @Justthebenno Thanks for your thoughts, you've given me much to consider. Note however that social logins on Xamarin [appear to be possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator) without a dedicated oidc server (haven't read it yet, but looks promising). I wouldn't have considered this issue if you hadn't pointed it out!

Comment: Still seems like a dedicated server is overkill for "simple" non-enterprise systems. I'm beginning to think this is not a technical matter, but a commercial one on behalf of MSFT. On other platforms I've done token auth (go, node) this sort of thing isn't needed, and of course on aspnet with a single client (spa or mobile) this is also not "needed", though it is useful.

Comment: I'm curious about what direction you will go. The article's procedure looks very promising, and it's a way I didn't know before. Thank you for that. Maybe, you can update the questions once you have decided. I can imagine that others facing the same decision